# Can I use Powerline WiFi Extenders for long distance wifi extention?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

Say the distance between home 1 and home 2 is 80 meters. Home 1 has good internet. I want to extend this internet to home 2 using the below device
TP-Link AV600 300Mbps Powerline Wi-Fi Extender Starter Kit

https://www.amazon.in/Tp-Link-TL-WPA4220-Wireless-Powerline-Extender/dp/B00C2ICYPC

Is it possible? What is the maximum distance that the powerline wifi Extenders can be used?

Comment: If you're talking about two separate buildings fed from separate transformers, I strongly doubt the signals put on top of the power lines will make it past the first building's transformer--and I'm pretty sure if they *did* it would be illegal, you're not generally supposed to mess with public power transmission circuitry.

Comment: Unlikely, but high power WiFi is possible.

Comment: @Hearth I agree about transformers getting in the way, but I doubt it would be illegal as the devices would not be legal to sell if it were - AFAIK they are indiscriminate about which wires power is trnansmitted through. Of-course, its possible both houses share 1 feed - that is not uncommon in NZ where there is, for example, a main house and a secondary dwelling on 1 title.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75High power wifi - no - that would require $$$$$$$ licenses.  Regular power WIFI with directional antennas could work, especially if you keep out the 2.4 gig band.

Comment: I recall a small NE seaside town in NZ with WiFi extended with Yagi's along the coast.  this increases the 20 dB CE limit by 12 dB gain

Comment: no license  30 dBm here in Canada & US  I can pick up a half a dozen houses 11 Mbps is good to -87 dBm, 54 MBps to -77 dBm

Comment: @davidgo That was my point--if it could get onto the power grid, I would think it wouldn't be legal, so it wouldn't be sold if that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum theoretical distance for most powerline adapters is 300 meters, but you are unlikely to reach that in real life.

The actual distance will depend on a lot of factors in cludong noise on the line and thinks like RCD's and meters between circuits.

Its possible, but probably not practical between 2 seperately metered homes. If you have line-of-site between the locations You might be better off looking at  WIFI with highly directional antennas, ideally outside the 2.4 g band unless you live in a rural area.  (Under reasonable real world conditions WIFI can easily go much further then 80 meters (indeed shots over kilometers are doable)

Comment: Say.. I layed a dedicated power line from home1 to home 2. No tapping in between. Home one, I connect transmitter of the PLC - Powerline Communication device and other end (home2) receiver unit of the PLC device. So still are there any challenges?

Comment: @intruder2t At that point, why not lay something designed for RF like low-loss coax or even single-mode optical fiber? There are much better ways to get signals across long distances than random power cables.

Comment: @intruder2 - if there were no RCD or equivalent protection between the 2 plugs in the scenario you are talking about it shpuld work.  Add an rcd or similar and the bets are off - it may or may not work.  (in many parts of the world an RCD/TCBO on the circuit is required.). Of you are trenching consider running a fibre cable and a couple of media convertors for much greater speed and reliability.  Alternatively if you can practically keep 8cm/200mm separation  in a trench you can run regular ethernet in a conduit or direct bury ethernet...

Comment: Correct. But optical solution may be costly. And how about extending the same for elevator.? 230 V powerline is already available in the traveling cable. All needed is couple of plug points to insert the transmitter in the machine room and one inside the elevator car for receiver. No extra cost is involved here and installation is easy. Just want to know if this works or not.

Comment: The only way to know if it works in an environment which is not very tightly specced is to try it.At my previous place I had 1 manufacturers ethernet over power work, while anothers didn't. (5g wireless worked way better)  I postulate it would not work great in an environment with heavy electric machinary due to wideband interference spewed out by motors.  In the case of buildings I would look for a riser - comms/electrical/water risers are, I believe, pretty standard.